# Change time output format in php date calculation

Tags: php, unix, timestamp

Ok, i'm not a coder, I need to make a little php tweak on a line of code and have spent many hours trying to figure out how to do it. There are many tutorials about time format in php but I can't find the answer to my necessity.

I have this line of code in an application:

```
<span class="muted">Expires in <?=(now() > $l->list_expires) ? 'Closed' : timespan(now(),$l->list_expires)?></span>
```

I discovered that 'list_expires' is a mysql column with a unix time date in the future, i.e. 1479350850.
The code calculates the time from now to the future date and outputs the result like this:
Coija.com Expires in 4 Weeks, 1 Day, 21 Hours, 30 Minutes

What I want is to display the result in a shorter manner, like say, 'Expires in 29 days' and if it is less that one day, 'Expires in 13 hours' or 'Expires in 10 minutes'. Another option would be '29 days left'.

I know the first part checks if the time expired and outputs 'closed', but right now, if it is closed the output is: 'Expired in closed'.
How can I not show 'Expired' if 'closed' must be shown?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `If (expired) { don't show closed }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I discovered that 'timespan' here is not a php command but a function in a script. Right now, I'm starting to play whit that to see the results.

Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample timespan function:

```
function timespan ($current_time, $list_expires) {
    /** The formatted time span */
    $formatted_timespan = "";
    /** The difference between the current time and list expires */
    $time_difference = ($current_time - $list_expires);
    /** If the time difference is greater than 1 day */
    if ($time_difference > (3600*24)) {
        /** The number of days */
        $day_count          = floor($time_difference / (3600*24));
        $formatted_timespan = "Expires in " . $day_count . " days";
    }
    /** If the time difference is less than 1 day but larger than 1 hour */
    else ($time_difference < (3600*24) && $time_difference > (3600)) {
        /** The number of hours */
        $hour_count         = floor($time_difference / (3600));
        $formatted_timespan = "Expires in " . $hour_count . " hours";
    }
    /** If the time difference is less than 1 hour */
    else ($time_difference < (3600)) {
        /** The number of minutes */
        $minute_count       = floor($time_difference / (60));
        $formatted_timespan = "Expires in " . $minute_count . " minutes";
    }
    return $formatted_timespan;
}
```